# Variable to affect single item in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat listing items with a button inside, which updates certain info from this item into the DB and then retrieves the new object.

I'm trying to show a loading gif while this happens, but so far the gif appears on all items of the ng-repeat, as I'm using a $scope variable.

Like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="fair in allfairs">
  <img ng-show="loading" src="../images/loading.gif">
  <a ng-click="deactivate(fair)" ng-if="!loading">Deactivate</a>
</div>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.deactivate = function(fair){
  $scope.loading = true;

  var $promisedb=$http.post('databaseconnect/updatefair.php',$scope.activated);

  $promisedb.then(function (data) {
    $scope.loading = false;
  });
};
```

How could I achieve the same but only for the particular item that I'm clicking on without affecting the whole array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the `item` to a scope variable instead and compare item to that scope variable in `ng-if`

```
$scope.deactivate = function(fair){
  $scope.loadingItem = fair;

  var $promisedb=$http.post('databaseconnect/updatefair.php',$scope.activated);

  $promisedb.then(function (data) {
    $scope.loadingItem = false
  });
};
```

View

```
<a ng-click="deactivate(fair)" ng-if="loadingItem != fair">Deactivate</a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work! Even that I predefine `$scope.loadingItem = false;` outside of the function, the link won't appear on load. And when I add `ng-if="loadingItem = fair"` for the image (to appear only while function), it appears all the time...

Answer (score 1):

You can chain the img element and a element together via $index of the array allfairs,and you must change the type of loading to object {},when you click the a element,you should add a item to loading,and you can take the $index as the key of item.The loading gif which has a $index will be affected by same $index which has clicked on a element. The code looks like below:

```
<div ng-repeat="fair in allfairs">
  <img ng-show="loading[$index]" src="../images/loading.gif">
  <a ng-click="deactivate(fair,$index)" ng-if="!loading[$index]">Deactivate</a>
</div>

$scope.loading = {};
$scope.deactivate = function(fair,index){
  $scope.loading[index] = true;

  var $promisedb=$http.post('databaseconnect/updatefair.php',$scope.activated);

  $promisedb.then(function (data) {
    $scope.loading[index] = false;
  });
};
```